# Where to look (for a c++ starter) to create a suspend process program for Windows Vista x64 Ultimate?

Tags: c++, windows

I want to suspend or save a state of Windows Wista with all opened applications and close them (to have be reopened again later), and start a game (from Steam for example). And when I will quit a game, I want to resume (resume saved state, or resume from suspend) all opened applications to resume work where I left it. I have found this relevant resources:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319950/Creating-your-own-library-in-visual-studio
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/will-windows-8-have-this-feature/8392475d-c5c8-4996-b387-418bc673688c
- https://superuser.com/questions/230818/windows-software-to-save-arbitrary-application-state

  > a "Windows state saver" Application. It is just save active state and close active windows applications/or session, and start a game. And when quit game just resume windows state with all active applications that was before suspend, to resume work after playing a game

Can you point me advice on how to create such a feature? I'm just starting with C++, where to look first for a start, and nothing more, just a starting point with resources. To create such a program for Windows Vista x64 Ultimate, I have learned pretty much about C++.

More about the same: Can I make to "Hibernate" only active programs, and leave windows OS active? Is this just need to launch another explorer.exe?

Comment: your question is unclear. Can you elaborate a bit about what is a suspend process program?

Comment: This feature is already in Windows. It's called Hibernate, I believe.

Comment: Here is how I asked same question 3 months ago: How to "like a hibernate" all opened applications and stay MS Windows with PC Power On and launch a game, and when I quit playing a game to turn hibernate PC back with all the big number of applications opened to resume working later when played a game? Will new windows 8 be have this feature?

Comment: Saulius I moved your first comment into the question itself, please don't add clarifications in comments, always revise the question.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a difficult project for a beginner. You'll have to learn quite a bit about the internals of the operating system: process control and how to manipulate virtual memory. A few books you might start with are [Windows via C/C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735624240), [Windows System Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321657748), and [Windows Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735625301). A new edition of Windows Internals is coming out in March.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you better don't try to write a program for this purpose on your own. Instead, get a virtualization software like VMWare, Virtual PC or Virtual Box, and run your application stack in the virtual environment. Then it will be really easy to freeze your applications' state, and continue them later.

Comment: but it will be virtual? not real D:\ disk partition? And I will lose my data when I delete virtual partition?

Comment: in VMware Player 4 is Virtual disk device :) not a real Folder or Drive Partition. Is in VMware Workstation the same, is it real Folder or Disk Drive?

Comment: VMware Workstation can have physical disk drive partition. http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/disks_dualmult_ws.html. This is close to problem solving. But not good choice, because virtual OS in VMware is slower.

Comment: I found I can use Shared Folders in VMware Player.